# get row content by field from DataGridRow

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` with several columns in my application.. I need to use different row foreground colour in case of some certain field content. I use following callback on `LoadingRow`event:

```
 void userGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e){

            if (e.Row.Item != null){  
                // check some row's field value               
                ...
                // modify row forecolor
                e.Row.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                ...
            }
        }
```

But how to get value of some certain row's field by it's name or index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   void userGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
   {
        var dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
        IEnumrable<DataGridRow> rows = dataGrid.Items.Where(r =>  (r.DataContext as YourItemsSourceEntity).SomeProperty == yourCondition)
   }
```

Alternatively i would add a condition to your ItemsSource  .

```
        public class YourItemsSourceEntity
        {
             public bool IsSomething { get; }
        }
```

xaml :

```
     <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSomething}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>                
    </DataGrid>
```

as to the comment below :  Is this what you ment ?

```
    void userGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
   {
        var item = e.Row.DataContext as (YourItemsSourceEntity);
        var id = item.ID ;   
   }
```

Comment: it seems like `DataGrid` doesn't have member `Rows`. In fact I want to receive value of the field first, not to apply contition directly.

Comment: try Items  , see Edit answer , 
I didn't understand what you meant by "I want to receive value of the field first, not to apply contition directly"

Comment: when this event occurs, my function is called and event parameter contains row, was added. For example there is column named "id" in my grid. I want to get "id" column value for added row. That I meant.